# Using JQuery to dynamically write an accordion-menu with JSON.NET

Tags: jquery, html, json, json.net, accordion

I have written an accordion menu in HTML/jQuery. I use JSON to load the information into the accordion dynamically. The problem is that my original JSON was written in a specific format - a format which I understood and knew how to access through jQuery.

I started to use JSON.NET to serialize my data into a JSON object (easy and effective). To give you an example:

Previous JSON-format (this was hardcoded):

```
{
    "Country": [
        {
            "CountryName": "exampleCountry",
            "Region": [
                {
                    "RegionName": "exampleRegion",
                    "SubRegion": [
                        {
                            "SubRegionName": "exampleSubRegion"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON.NET output format (retrieved from a database):

```
[
  {
    "Country": "exampleCountry",
    "Region": "exampleRegion",
    "SubRegion": "exampleRegion"
  }
]
```

My accordion is supposed to look like:

```
---Country---
    ---exampleCountry1---
        ---exampleRegion1---
        ---exampleRegion2---
        ---exampleRegion3---
            ---exampleSubRegion1---
            ---exampleSubRegion2---
            ---exampleSubRegion3---
    ---exampleCountry2---
    ---exampleCountry3---
```

This is the jQuery I used to return the values from my original JSON file:

```
$.getJSON('example.json', function (cwData) {
    $.each(cwData.Country, function (i, country) { // loop through all the countries
        var countries = '<li class="country_name"><a href="#">' + country.CountryName + '</a></li>'; // the name of the country
        var country_region = '<ul class="country_region">'; // create a list of all the regions in the country

        $.each(Country.Region, function (i, region) { // loop through all the regions
            country_region += '<li class="region_name"><a href="#">' + region.RegionName + '</a></li>'; // the name of the region
            var region_subregion = '<ul class="region_subregion">'; // create a list of all the subregions in the region

            $.each(Region.SubRegion, function (i, subregion) { // loop through all the regions
                region_subregion += '<li class="subregion_name"><a href="#">' + subregion.SubRegionName + '</a></li>'; // the name of the subregion
            });
            region_subregion += '</u>'; //close the list tags
            $(region_subregion).appendTo(country_region); // append the subregion to the region
        });
        country_region += '</ul>'; //close the list tags
        $(countries).appendTo('#accordion_menu').append(country_region); // append the region to the country and append the country to the accorion menu
    });
});
```

I have added as much comments as possible to make the content more readable/understandable.
As you may have noticed - the previous JSON had more of an "hierarchy"-structure as opposed to the new JSON which has more of a "flat"-structure.

Would it be possible to **access and manipulate** the JSON.NET using jQuery to build the accordion dynamically? And if so, how would I do that? Could the solution be to change the way I store my data into the serialized object?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it would be possible to use AJAX calls from the client to get pieces of your accordion from the server and then update the UI dynamically.  But to do this, you pretty much have to change everything about how your code works now:

- You'll have to write a server side API to allow retrieving just the piece you want;
- You'll probably have to change your database queries to work with the API;
- You'll have to change your UI/jQuery code to make the calls when the user clicks in the accordion.
- The UI will be less responsive than it would be if it had all the data up front.

Since you already have your UI code working with a hierarchical structure, I think the better solution is to make your server convert the flat subregion list into the hierarchical format that the UI expects.